# Trying to generate a html file from PHP code

Tags: php, html, frontend

I have a PHP program from OpenEMR that prints context to the console in HTML format. I wanted to save whatever it prints to another html file. I am not very familiar with PHP and front end technologies. Does anyone know a simple way to make it work? Thanks a lot.

Below is the code detail:

```
foreach($newpatient as $patient){
        /*
        $inclookupres = sqlStatement("select distinct formdir from forms where pid='".$pids[$iCounter]."'");
        while($result = sqlFetchArray($inclookupres)) {
            include_once("{$GLOBALS['incdir']}/forms/" . $result{"formdir"} . "/report.php");
        }
        */

        print "<div id='superbill_patientdata'>";
        print "<h1>".xlt('Patient Data').":</h1>";
        printRecDataOne($patient_data_array, getRecPatientData ($pids[$iCounter]), $N);
        print "</div>";

        print "<div id='superbill_insurancedata'>";
        print "<h1>".xlt('Insurance Data').":</h1>";
        print "<h2>".xlt('Primary').":</h2>";
        printRecDataOne($insurance_data_array, getRecInsuranceData ($pids[$iCounter],"primary"), $N);
        print "<h2>".xlt('Secondary').":</h2>";
        printRecDataOne($insurance_data_array, getRecInsuranceData ($pids[$iCounter],"secondary"), $N);
        print "<h2>".xlt('Tertiary').":</h2>";
        printRecDataOne($insurance_data_array, getRecInsuranceData ($pids[$iCounter],"tertiary"), $N);
        print "</div>";

        print "<div id='superbill_billingdata'>";
        print "<h1>".xlt('Billing Information').":</h1>";
        if (count($patient) > 0) {
            $billings = array();
            echo "<table width='100%'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='bold' width='10%'>".xlt('Date')."</td>";
            echo "<td class='bold' width='20%'>".xlt('Provider')."</td>";
            echo "<td class='bold' width='40%'>".xlt('Code')."</td>";
            echo "<td class='bold' width='10%'>".xlt('Fee')."</td></tr>\n";
            $total = 0.00;
            $copays = 0.00;
            //foreach ($patient as $be) {

                $ta = split(":",$patient);
                $billing = getPatientBillingEncounter($pids[$iCounter],$ta[1]);

                $billings[] = $billing;
                foreach ($billing as $b) {
                    // grab the date to reformat it in the output
                    $bdate = strtotime($b['date']);

                    echo "<tr>\n";
                    echo "<td class='text' style='font-size: 0.8em'>" . oeFormatShortDate(date("Y-m-d",$bdate)) . "<BR>" . date("h:i a", $bdate) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class='text'>" . text($b['provider_name']) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class='text'>";
                    echo text($b['code_type']) . ":\t" . text($b['code']) . "&nbsp;". text($b['modifier']) . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . text($b['code_text']) . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    echo "</td>\n";
                    echo "<td class='text'>";
                    echo oeFormatMoney($b['fee']);
                    echo "</td>\n";
                    echo "</tr>\n";
                    $total += $b['fee'];
                }
            // Calculate the copay for the encounter
            $copays = getPatientCopay($pids[$iCounter],$ta[1]);
            //}
            echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td class='bold' colspan=3 style='text-align:right'>".xlt('Sub-Total')."</td><td class='text'>" . oeFormatMoney($total + abs($copays)) . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td class='bold' colspan=3 style='text-align:right'>".xlt('Copay Paid')."</td><td class='text'>" . oeFormatMoney(abs($copays)) . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td class='bold' colspan=3 style='text-align:right'>".xlt('Total')."</td><td class='text'>" . oeFormatMoney($total) . "</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($billings);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
```

Comment: copy that code in a php file, for example
create index.php and paste the code inside
move the index.php in your server, for test in your machine you can use http://www.wampserver.com/en/

then access with your browser, example
http://localhost/your_project/index.php
there you go

Comment: @LuisCardenas Thank you for your comment. It runs good on my localhost; what I wanted to do is actually just save whatever it prints here to a html file. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: which software are you using to run this php code?

Comment: @LuisCardenas I'm simply using Notepad++ for editing it because I didn't develop any PHP programs before.

Comment: you can use output buffering. PHP has a few functions you can use to save to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
ob_start();
```

/*
YOUR CODE
*/

```
    $page= ob_get_contents();
    if ($fp = fopen('../page.htm', 'w+')) {
    fwrite ($fp, $page);
    fclose($fp);
    }

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It perfectly solved my problem